# Bearer undefined in wso2 api manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I published my API in wso2 API Manager when I tried it out in the developer portal. I got the error Bearer undefined in a curl command.

```
curl -X GET "https://localhost:8243/meter/1/?ConsumerID=LTFAREERKC&StartDate=01-05-2022  EndDate=02-05-2022" -H "accept: */*" -H "Authorization: Basic QREYUREFBE H: Bearer undefined"
```

Comment: Hi riya, did you subscribe your API to an application and generate an access token from the developer portal?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Authorization header you send in the curl command, it must contain "Bearer " and not "Basic ".

Example:

```
-H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN>"
```

Do not forget to generate the Access Token.